# Tagging Schema for Multiple Entities

Tags: entity-framework, database-schema, tagging

Bear with me...

I'm implementing an application that has multiple unrelated classes that need to share a common tagging mechanism.  This should allow (among other things) to search by tags across multiple entities; or even creating soft-relationships by shared tags in otherwise-unrelated items.

When working with Entity Framework Code First I did not find so far a solution that I consider acceptable. Below is a description of the design attemps I tried:

Assumptions:
"Tag" entity.
"Article" entity, can be tagged.
"Post" entity, can be tagged.
"Other" type: just any other type that can be tagged with no relationship to the previous ones.

**Option 1: One common "EntityTag" class with multiple Foreign Keys.**

The approach consists in creating an "EntityTag" junciton-entity that generates an "EntityTags" junction-table and has multiple nullable Foreign Keys to each of the entities that can be tagged.

PROs:
- Single type simplifies further development (UI, Search Queries, etc.)

CONs:
- Bad database design
- Need to reinforce DB constraints in code (at least have one value selected, etc.)
- SaveChanges and other EF methods need to cleanup orphaned EntityTags

**Option 2: One type per relationship.**

This approach has one type per junction-table/entity required. There is a base "EntityTag" type with the TagId and Tag navigation properties.
For example: "ArticleTag", "PostTag", "OtherTag", etc.

PROs:
- Looks like a better normalized database design
- No cleanup nor constraint reinforcement required in code

CONs:
- Painful to do cross-entity queries, as you need to reference the junction-tables separately and relate them with their parents
- Also painful to work with views, as trying to use the base class is somewhat strange due to collection casting and variance-covariance
- I had to refactor the Services, Repositories, etc. to define the type of tagging entity on the generics, which also looked quite cumbersome (and horrible)

**Option 3: base class for any entity that can be tagged (supertyping/subtyping)**

This approach considers having a base "Entity" class only containing an Id (and maybe auditing columns), and having any other entity type inherit from this one.
For example: Article -> Entity, Post -> Entity, etc.
Then there is a single "EntityTag" junction-type/table that relates ANY entity with tags.

PROs:
- Simplifies the syntax and coding (at least compared with option 2!)
- Base class can serve to do common auditing (unrelated to tagging, but useful)
- Very simple queries, as any type can use their common "EntityTags" navigation property if need to apply filtering
- Working with Views is also very simple, as they all deal with EntityTag

CONs:
- Scared about the implications as the solution grows.
- The generated SQL queries become more complex, as they need to join with the SuperType and in turn join with the Tags
- From a pure Domain Driven (or even Object Modeling) perspective, there is really NO relationship between the types. This is forced by the Persistence layer, which is contrary to proper DDD.
- In some cases, there may be a shared relationship between BlogPost and NewsArticle. Let's assume for example "Files". Each BlogPost and NewsArticle can have Files. In this case, only those 2 types can have them, but in order to move forward with the base class approach, then each 2 types sharing something would need to have base class, which is simply not possible.
I thought about doing some magic with "protected internal" and exposing Public properties from the base class ONLY when the entities are actually meant to have them.
This will end up having a "God" base class, and then allowing to "attach/expose" things on the subclasses. This has some design smell...

**Option 4: the one I'm asking you to provide**

Really what this is to me is the good old conflict of "Inheritance VS Composition".
I would like Entity Framework to be able to just interpret my Composition through interfaces (ITaggable, IFileCollector, etc.) and translate that into a DB Schema.
By restricting to base classes and inheritance, it forces some unnatural relationships and adds additional unnecessary complexity (and less-correctness) to the Domain layer.

Another approach would be to just decouple Persistence model from Domain model, having 2 separate sets of entities. I was expecting EF Code First to provide a way NOT to decouple those, and just have a single model.

If you've read so far, thank you for your time!

Comment: This is about *polymorphic associations*. Once you know this term you should be able to find lots of questions & answers on this subject. I'd suggest you do further research and come back if this still leaves you with a code-related question. In its present state the question is too broad anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Gert, if you have the knowledge about the right solution it would be fantastic if you can share it with the rest of the community.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your question? I did chose option 2 in my case, as it is the most simple for cross-query search

Comment: In most scenarios, I would suggest Option 2. The complexity and potential consequences of Options 1 and 3 are probably not worth the trade-off.

Comment: I was just about to implement something like option 3, but did the search first. Your question is exactly what I put into search.. Anyway, thanks for you question/answers, I will go with opt2.